# Drawing rectangle in EA

Tags: mql4

I hope to draw a rectangle surrounds two bars in EA which satisfies certain condition, like

```
if (...){//satisfy condition
    //todo: code for draw a bar of current and previous candle

}
```

I am aware of the function of create rectangle

```
ObjectCreate("Rectangle", OBJ_RECTANGLE, 0, Time[0], price1, Time[1], price2);
```

But how to manipulate it to draw the rectangle exactly in graph?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to edit some parameters of the object, you need functions `ObjectSet()` or `ObjectSetDouble();ObjectSetInteger(); ObjectSetString()`. To change date or color or location in case of labels - use `ObjectSetInteger(0,name_of_your_object,OBJPROP_TIME1, your_value);`
(full list of properties [here](https://docs.mql4.com/ru/constants/objectconstants/enum_object_property#enum_object_property_integer).

For price coordinates of the rectangle - use `ObjectSetDouble(0,name,OBJPROP_PRICE1,value)` or `OBJPROP_PRICE2` since it has 2 price and two time coordinates.

Comment: Hi daniel, why not just passed the price values in the ObjectCreate directly? (that is price1 and price2)..My question is how should I specify this two parameters so that I could get the rectangle in the graph?

Comment: if you do not have an object on chart - you can create with parameters. if you have an object with that name - function returns false and not move the object to the right place. so i think it's always better to create with 0's and then move. I am not sure that i understood your question - you want to know how to find price values or datetime values in order to use them for placing your rectangle, dont you?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I post a new question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674261/blue-border-surrounding-two-candles) with code, could help to see how to make it work?